# How to change the Cursor to Hourglass for a particular control in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I trying to change the cursor to the Hourglass, I have done this way:

```
this.Cursor = Cursors.Wait;

<.... process ....>

this.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
```

The problem is that when the process is executing the cursor does not change to the hourglass and stays like that.

What must I do ?????

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

This thread on Microsoft's forum might be of interest to you:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/383b207d-2f7f-43d6-ba17-967dc3f1ad0d/

```
Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Wait;
/* Processing */
Mouse.OverrideCursor = null;
```

Comment: This changes the cursor for the entire application. The OP was asking to change it on a particular control.